# S4 Object Error when Trying to Access Tree

Tags: r, r-s4, party

I get this error:

```
> mod1 <- ctree(Age ~ Kyphosis, data = kyphosis)
> tree.size(mod1@tree)
Error in tree.size(mod1@tree) : 
  trying to get slot "tree" from an object (class "constparty") that is not an S4 object
```

Here, tree.size is defined as:

```
> tree.size
function(tree) {
  if (is.null(tree)) {
    return(0)
  } else {
    return(1 + tree.size(tree$left) + tree.size(tree$right))
  }
}
```

How do I get rid of this error and why is it occurring?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the @-operator, that requires an S4 object.
I guess, ctree() returns an S3 object instead of S4. The $-operator would be appropriate in that case (as used in tree.size).